# Autopopulate a Checkbox in Word 2013 Using IF Statement

Tags: ms-word, word-field

I would like to auto populate/tick a checkbox in Word 2013 when the conditions are met for the following IF statement:

```
IF <<Case_FilingDate>>="true" "This box is checked." "This box is not checked."
```

What I do want:

- When the statement is true the checkbox is automatically populated/ticked.

What I do not want:

- The statement "This box is checked" to appear or the statement "This box is not checked" to appear.
- The user to manually check the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to approach this is to include the "checked" and "unchecked" boxes as static font characters in the `If` field result sets. So the (fully expanded) field code would look like this

```
{ IF { MergeField Case_FilingDate } = true "[Symbol]" "[Symbol]" }
```

In order to insert the checkboxes where I've typed the `[Symbol]` placeholders Insert->Symbol can be used. The two characters shown in the screen shot (below) I found in the font Wingdings 2.

The screen-shot shows how I created a bookmark (for the test, since I don't have the merge data), set that value, tested the value in the `If` field, and then at the bottom the `If` field result for the `false` value.

[image]

A note for anyone reading this who would want a checkbox that can be checked: This would not be possible because the control is nested in a ***field***.